# Creating a Hermitian matrix that is also positive semi-definite

Tags: complex-numbers, spectral-graph-theory, graph-laplacian

Given some measurements on empirical data (in the form of a multigraph with two weighted edges between every pair of vertices), I would like to place the measurements in a Hermitian matrix that also (1) resembles a Laplacian matrix and (2) is positive semi-definite.

The goal is to measure algebraic connectivity (i.e., the second smallest eigenvalue) while simultaneously considering two types of edge weights.

My measurements are both on the [0,1] interval and I think this is a problem. From what I have read (Wilson and Hancock, Spectral Analysis of Complex Laplacian Matrices), each entry on the diagonal must be greater than the sum of magnitudes of the off-diagonal entries on the same row/column. They seem to recommend adding some positive constant, if necessary.

Can anyone recommend a procedure for obtaining this matrix? In particular, how should I scale my measurements? Should my measurements be treated as the magnitude and phase of the complex entries (as recommended by the reference above) or as the real and imaginary parts (my original hunch)?

Comment: Is your multigraph a directed graph?

Comment: No. The connections are symmetric.

Comment: Is there any reason that you didn't just take both of the edges between a pair of vertices and combine them into one edge whose weight is the sum of the two edge-weights?

Comment: I have thought about simpler schemes, such as sums and products. It just seems like I will lose information that way. These measurements come from word lists made by patients-- for example, the semantic similarity of two words and the temporal proximity of the two words in the list. If I add or multiply, then unrelated words that are close together might look just like related words that are far apart. It would be nice to have a system that discerns between those possibilities.

Comment: My intuition is that you would want your graph to ultimately emphasize the total degree of connectedness between vertices.  Perhaps if you came up with some "exchange rate" between temporal proximity and similarity, you could add the weights together in a reasonable way.  I'm not sure what insight is gained by using complex weights.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, one of the matrices you want will be positive semidefinite.

In particular, let $w^{(1)}_{jk} = w^{(1)}_{kj}$ and $w^{(2)}_{jk}=w^{(2)}_{kj}$ be the weights between vertices $j$ and $k$.
We can define the matrix $M$ by
$$
M_{jk} = -w^{(1)}_{jk} - i \, w^{(2)}_{jk} \quad j<k\\
M_{kk} = \sum_{j=1}^n \sqrt{(w^{(1)}_{jk})^2 + (w^{(2)}_{jk})^2}\\
M_{jk} = \overline{M_{kj}}
$$
This matrix is directly analogous to the Laplacian.

Comment: Thank you for taking time to answer my question. Should the real part of the off-diagonal entries be negated? Should it be the sum of the square roots that go into the on-diagonal entries (i.e., the sum of magnitudes of the off-diagonal entries)? I believe the row and column sums should be zero if the new matrix is to look like a Laplacian. Should I expect the smallest eigenvalue to be zero, as with real Laplacians? Will the second smallest eigenvalue still be a measure of connectivity?

Comment: My mistake; yes, you should negate the diagonal entries as I gave them (or just negate the real part, if you prefer)

Comment: Yes, it should be the sum of the square roots on the diagonal

Comment: I do *not* believe that we can guarantee an eigenvalue of $0$, even with these corrections, so that is a bit of an oversight

Comment: I am not sufficiently reputable to upvote your answer.

Comment: @DavidC don't worry about it. Glad the answer helped.